# Any API can get Users of "firebase realtime analytics"?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We want to get "the users in last 30 minutes" as below image.
Any API can get that? Or, possible got this from BigQuery data?

[image]

Updated, This is the code I tried later, hope it helps.

```
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    Metric,
    MinuteRange,
    RunRealtimeReportRequest,
)


def sample_run_report(property_id="123456789"):
    """Runs a simple report on a Google Analytics 4 property."""
    # TODO(developer): Uncomment this variable and replace with your
    #  Google Analytics 4 property ID before running the sample.
    # property_id = "YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"

    # Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
    # specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()

    request = RunRealtimeReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        metrics=[Metric(name="activeUsers")],
        minute_ranges=[
            MinuteRange(name="0-29 minutes ago", start_minutes_ago=29),
        ],
    )
    response = client.run_realtime_report(request)

    print("Report result:")
    for row in response.rows:
        print(row.metric_values[0].value)
        # print(row.dimension_values[0].value, row.metric_values[0].value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're asking about the realtime report of Google Analytics, that data would have to be in the results of calling [`properties.runRealtimeReport`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) of the [Google Analytics 4 Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1).

Comment: Thank you, indeed the page method can be used. I didn't know why I couldn't find a way before. Maybe the word "firebase" was added, and then I haven't found it.